# Unable to mount a cifs share in Centos, and from Windows clients which are not domain joined

Tags: centos, samba, cifs

We have a departmental file share and using "mount.cifs" in Centos works to connect to the share. 
 Windows clients either standalone or domain joined can access the share.    Fine !!

We have a Dell storage device running FluidFS.  Only Windows clients which are domain joined can connect.

- Non domain joined workstations give the

  ```
  The specified network password is not correct
  ```

  error.
- The Centos machine gives

  ```
  mount error(13): Permission denied
  ```

I have tried all values for the `sec` option in Centos.

Centos extract from `/var/log/messages`

```
May 19 15:33:25 backup kernel: No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.

May 19 15:33:25 backup kernel: Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE

May 19 15:33:25 backup kernel: CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
```

I don't understand what's going on. Any advice is welcome.

George

Comment: do you have access to the share with `smbclient` ?

Comment: For your non-domain joined clients, what shape username do you use? It should probably be DOMAIN\username not username@dom.ain. (And remember, on UNIX/Linux platforms, you need to single-quote the DOMAIN\username component if it's directly on the command line.)

Comment: Oh yes, on non-domain windows clients I am using the DOMAIN\username syntax. The issue described is only apparent on one fileserver. All others work as expected.

Comment: Any useful logs on the Dell side?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe I have access to it. I did an experiment. I build a Windows 2012 server vm. Tried to connect using DOMAIN\username.  Failed. Joined the vm to the domain and tried again. Succeeded.   Removed the vm from the domain and tried again. Failed.

Comment: I think this would also be worth taking up with your Windows admins - if I've read your question correctly, a non-domain joined Windows workstation has a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps: the main part, use the windows hostname as domain int the mount syntax.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/767422/cifs-smb-cant-mount-permission-denied-or-navigate-shared-folder